# Laravel Datatables NOT working, NO error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

When i visit the page, i just get the "Processing" but nothing is happening. Ive looked at the javascript console in chrome and i dont get any errors.. so im doing something wrong, but i dont know what it is. At first i thought it was the JSON output not being properly formatted, but i check it against jsonlint.com

Im sure this is something simple im over looking... Please?

The blog data controller

```
public function data()
{
    $posts = Post::select(array('posts.id', 'posts.title', 'posts.id as comments', 'posts.created_at'));
    return Datatables::of($posts)
    ->edit_column('comments', '{{ DB::table(\'comments\')->where(\'post_id\', \'=\', $id)->count() }}')
    ->add_column('actions', '<a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/blog/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs iframe" >{{{ Lang::get(\'button.edit\') }}}</a>
            <a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/blog/\' . $id . \'/delete\' ) }}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger iframe">{{{ Lang::get(\'button.delete\') }}}</a>
        ')
    ->remove_column('id')
    ->make();
}
```

The javascript:

```
<table id="posts" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>{{{ Lang::get('table.actions') }}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
@stop

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oTable;
    $(document).ready(function() {
            oTable = $('#posts').dataTable({
            "sDom": "<l><f><r>t<i><p>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Search:",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
            },
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::to('admin/blog/data') }}"
        });

        $("#users_filter input").addClass("form-control inline-control input-sm");
        $("#users_length select").addClass("form-control inline-control");
    });
</script>
@stop
```

UPDATE:
The data tables works just fine on my localhost, but as soon as i pull the repo down to my production server it doesn't work.

Here is the json data

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[[1,"First Post","<p>Welcome to my new blog. It&#39;s still under development and there are constantly changes being made. Just today i got CKEditor working on my blog admin, so that i could put HTML into my posts. Thi...<\/p>","1","2014-06-08 04:12:14","<a href=\"http:\/\/www.asdasd.com\/admin\/blog\/1\/edit\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs iframe\" >Edit<\/a>\n                <a href=\"http:\/\/www.asdaf.com\/admin\/blog\/1\/delete\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger iframe\">Delete<\/a>\n            "],[2,"second","yep its working","1","2014-06-08 05:58:13","<a href=\"http:\/\/www.asdaf.com\/admin\/blog\/2\/edit\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs iframe\" >Edit<\/a>\n                <a href=\"http:\/\/www.asdaf.com\/admin\/blog\/2\/delete\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger iframe\">Delete<\/a>\n            "]],"sColumns":["posts.id","posts.title","posts.content","posts.id as comments","posts.created_at","actions"],"aQueries":[{"query":"select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1","bindings":[1],"time":1.1},{"query":"select `roles`.*, `assigned_roles`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `assigned_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `assigned_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `assigned_roles`.`role_id` where `assigned_roles`.`user_id` = ?","bindings":[1],"time":0.99},{"query":"select `posts`.`id`, `posts`.`title`, `posts`.`content`, `posts`.`id` as `comments`, `posts`.`created_at` from `posts`","bindings":[],"time":3.98},{"query":"select count(*) as aggregate from `comments` where `post_id` = ?","bindings":[1],"time":2.34},{"query":"select count(*) as aggregate from `comments` where `post_id` = ?","bindings":[2],"time":0.73}]}
```

Here is what the app/storage/logs/log-cgi-fcgi-2014-06-21.txt

```
[2014-06-21 22:19:30] production.INFO: index [] []
[2014-06-21 22:19:31] production.INFO: data [] []
```

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: bllim/laravel4-datatables-package

Comment: What do you get when you go to your `admin/blog/data` directly in your browser?

Comment: The correct json output verified by jsonlint.

Comment: So it works on my LOCALHOST, but it does not work on my PRODUCTION environment. Its the exact same git repo. Does data tables have some sort of config for dev and production?

Comment: Any errors in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`? Can you view your page source and see where `{{ URL::to('admin/blog/data') }}` is pointing to?

Comment: I've added the requested data.

Comment: Why your model logic is inside a controller?

Comment: @Scorpion are you talking about the data function? how would you use the datatables package? is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I have 2 different version of the datatable.js file. Im guessing variables were overwriting eachother... but as soon as i upgraded everything to the same version it was working.